# In Electron, how to allow users to pick a file path

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an Electron App in which when users click on a button I want to open file explorer (or Finder on Mac) for users to choose a path in their file system. Then I want to use this path to save a file.

The second part is quiet easy to achieve. I just need to use writeFile() from node File System API.

However I have gone through the full list of node File System API and I have found nothing allowing me to do the first part.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use dialogue module. Simple example for showing the file explorer will be:

```
  const {dialog} = require('electron')
  console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory', 'multiSelections']}))
```

Check this [link](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) for more information.